# split string input contains long numbers based on comma double quotes and brackets

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String like this
 ["1505213753057","1505213854042","1505537148455"]

I want to split it and store the values into Long Array.

```
String [] loanId = loanIds.split("\"?,(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\"?");
                Long[] data = new Long[loanId.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < loanId.length; i++) {
                    data[i] = Long.parseLong(loanId[i]);
                }
```

I am using this splitter but it is not working. Any help how to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like JSON, why don't you try JSON parse and parseLong ?

Comment: Can you help me in that. I am not able to understand it.

Comment: Please define your actual `string` on which you have to perform the operation.

Comment: ["1505213753057","1505213854042","1505537148455"] this is the string which I am getting in my RestAPI. I want to store it into Long Array.

Comment: It looks like a `string array` not `string`.

Comment: yeah it is String array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
String loanIds = "[\"1505213753057\",\"1505213854042\",\"1505537148455\"]";

loanIds = loanIds.replaceAll("(\\[\")|(\"\\])", "").replaceAll("\",\"", ",");
String [] loanId = loanIds.split(",");
Long[] data = new Long[loanId.length];
for (int i = 0; i < loanId.length; i++) {
    data[i] = Long.parseLong(loanId[i]);
    System.out.println(data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace`[` and `]` with `{` and `}`.

```
import java.util.*;
class check {
    public static void main(String ar[]){ 
        String str[] ={"1505213753057","1505213854042","1505537148455"};
        long ll[]=new long[str.length];
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
            ll[i]=Long.parseLong(str[i]);
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
            System.out.println(ll[i]);
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using regex as shown below :

```
package com.grsdev.stackoverflow.question170920.pack01;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class LongNumerString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String text="[\"1505213753057\",\"1505213854042\",\"1505537148455\"]";

        Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("\\d+");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);


        List<Long> list=new ArrayList<>(); 

        while(matcher.find()){
            list.add(Long.valueOf(matcher.group()));
        }


        System.out.println("longs  : "+list);



        Long [] array = new Long[list.size()];

        list.toArray(array);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

mainstring=["1505213753057","1505213854042","1505537148455"] 
Is this your String ?

If yes and u want to store all elements in long Array,then this myt be the solution

String stringWithoutBraces=mainstring.substring(1, mainstring.length()-1);

```
        List<Long> loanidlist=new ArrayList<>();
        String[] stringWithoutCommas=stringWithoutBraces.split(",");

        for(String splited:stringWithoutCommas){
            String eachElement=splited.substring(1,splited.length()-1);
            loanidlist.add(Long.parseLong(eachElement));
        }
        Long[] loanid=(Long[]) loanidlist.toArray(new Long[loanidlist.size()]);
```